# Retrieve Unix folder structure and permissions using C#

Tags: c#, .net, unix, permissions, ssh

As part of building an ASP.net application, I have to display two things for a specific user on an UNIX backend system:

- the folder structure
- the folder permissions (just notation like: drwxr-xr-x).

My knowledge of communicating to UNIX with C# is, however, very limited. I've discovered a few possiblities to accomplish this:

- FTP, not sure though whether I will be able see the permissions
- SSH, seems to be most common way to interact with UNIX from C# (command ls -ld should do)
- RSH, less secure than SSH? Apart from security, what's difference with SSH?

Questions:

- What is the best way to interact to UNIX using C#, knowing only the above two things have to be displayed?
- Perhaps some examples available somewhere (couldn't really find them yet)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you run ASP.NET from the UNIX machine you want to examine? Or, on another UNIX machine mounting the remote file system as sshfs/NFS

Comment: I can't do anything with the machine itself. Thought of mounting also, but I guess detailed folder permissions aren't visible that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code project looks like it would do what you want. In fact I think the screenshot is doing exactly what you're describing.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx